# Scale overflowing column to smaller one (bootstrap or vanilla css)

Tags: css, flexbox, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, overflow

I've tried several different approaches and I'm pretty sure it's not possible without JS - but before I curl up in a corner I thought I'd give it a try here.

I have one very long navigation div on the left and next to it a column with dynamic content. The first goal is to have the height of the navigation be max the same as the content and overflow the rest.

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br>more dynamic content...');
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.left {
  background: #ccc;
}

.right {
  background: #cc6;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">Long Navigation<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>Cookiemonster</div>
  <div class="right">Shorter Content...<br>...<br>
    <button id="add">+ add more content</button>
    <br>...<br>...<br>...<br>&lt;-- Navigation div should always end here</div>
</div>
```

---

To make it a bit more interesting the whole thing is in a modal. So my second goal is to get it to work in a div that has overflow: auto itself.

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br>more dynamic content...');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  
  margin: 10px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px grey;
}

.left {
  background: #ccc;
}

.right {
  background: #cc6;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="left">Long Navigation<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>Cookiemonster</div>
  <div class="right">Shorter Content...<br>...<br>
    <button id="add">+ add more content</button>
    <br>...<br>...<br>...<br>&lt;-- Navigation div should always end here</div>
</div>
```

I tried flexbox, positioning, and any combination of max-height, height and min-height that I could come up with but to no success. Do you have any idea how to achieve this without JS?

*Oh, and it has to work in IE11...* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to position the navigation absolutely but you would need to give the left div a fixed width

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br>more dynamic content...');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px grey;
}

.modal-inner {   /* add this div so backgrounds don't stop when they hit max-height of modal */
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;  /* add this and give a fixed width */
  width: 200px;
}

.absolute {
  /* add a div with this class inside the left column */
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.right {
  background: #cc6;
  flex-grow: 1;  /* add this if you want this div to fill the rest of width */
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-inner">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="absolute">
        Long Navigation<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>Cookiemonster</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">Shorter Content...<br>...<br>
      <button id="add">+ add more content</button>
      <br>...<br>...<br>...<br>&lt;-- Navigation div should always end here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! This does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!